# How to create a new web page using content in variables?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm not sure if my title makes sense, but essentially what i want to do is create a new webpage (.html or .php) when a button is clicked on the previous page, and use a template but only change a data based on a few variables.

Essentially what im trying to do is generate like a new post page based on the content the user uploads/provides. So it would be based off a html page/template that already exists but tweak a few variables to change the contents of the page (main image, audio file, etc)

Is this possible and what is the best practice way to do this or something to achieve a similar effect?

Like in the image below, id like to have a new page or something similar that allows the end user to see a different image and audio track based on what they upload on the previous pages...

[For example the image and audio track in this website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMBz4.jpg)

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Gersh

Comment: Thats basically why PHP was invented and what it does almost all the time. I would suggest that you search for "Basic PHP tutorial"

Comment: Are you familiar with databases and dynamic pages?

Comment: Not really no, not too familiar, I have used a bit of PHP to get the file upload working, so I have a very basic understanding of it.